API routes for Gitea workflow artifacts
I want to (automatically) download the build artifacts of a gitea action workflow to use them for further automated testing.
But unfortunately I can't find the correct API endpoints to automatically download the build artifacts.
I know that there is also actions/download-artifacts, but I want to download the artifacts from an external test pipeline (Jenkins).
I am using Gitea in version 1.21.7
The swagger also did not help: https://demo.gitea.com/api/swagger#/activitypub
Thanks for your help!
